# intelMKL - ZGEMM calls inside OMP parallel do region

Tags: for-loop, optimization, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I have matrices of maximum shape (2500 x 2500) , to be multiplied by vectors of maximum shape (2500, ), the result having of course a maximum shape of (2500, ).
These are all complex*16 datatype arrays.
Thus I use ZGEMM.

I am repeatedly calling ZGEMM inside a doubly nested do-loop.
The sequential code looks like this:

```
   complex*16 U(Nb, 0:lmax, 0:nphi), S(Nb, Nb, 0:lmax)

   complex*16 U2(Nb, 0:lmax, 0:nphi)

   integer j, l, m

   integer :: Nbvar
   complex*16 :: zerovar, onevar

   U2(:,:,:) = zerovar 

   do l = 0, lmax
     do m = 0, l
     call ZGEMM('N','N', Nbvar, 1, Nbvar, onevar, S(:,:,l), Nbvar,
 &               U(:,l,m), Nbvar, zerovar, U2(:,l,m), Nbvar)
     end do
     do m=nphi-l,nphi-1
     call ZGEMM('N','N', Nbvar, 1, Nbvar, onevar, S(:,:,l), Nbvar,
 &               U(:,l,m), Nbvar, zerovar, U2(:,l,m), Nbvar)
     end do
   end do
```

The parameters are : `Nb = 2500` at maximum, `lmax = 150-200` at maximum, and the relationship between `nphi` and `lmax` is: `nphi = 2*lmax + 2`.

Also, I have: `complex*16 zerovar, onevar`, then:

`zero = dcmplx(0.0d0, 0.0d0)` and

`one = dcmplx(1.0d0, 0.0d0)`.

The parallel attempt I made is:

```
       !$OMP PARALLEL DO FIRSTPRIVATE(Nbvar, onevar, zerovar)
!$OMP+ SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC)

       do l = 0, lmax
         do m = 0, l
         call ZGEMM('N','N', Nbvar, 1, Nbvar, onevar, S(:,:,l), Nbvar,
     &               U(:,l,m), Nbvar, zerovar, U2(:,l,m), Nbvar)
         end do
         do m=nphi-l,nphi-1
         call ZGEMM('N','N', Nbvar, 1, Nbvar, onevar, S(:,:,l), Nbvar,
     &               U(:,l,m), Nbvar, zerovar, U2(:,l,m), Nbvar)
         end do
       end do

       !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

is this the best I can get? Is there an obvious mistake seen by more experienced people?

I am setting the MKL number of threads and the OMP number of threads before these nested for loops as:

```
   call omp_set_num_threads(24)
   call mkl_set_num_threads(1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well without a complete code it's difficult to say much apart from wondering why you are using zgemm for matrix vector multiplies, and to note complex*16 is not standard fortran, has never been standard fortran, and should never be used. If you did provide a full code I suspect you could do better turning all those matrix vector multiplies into proper matrix matrix ones but as presented I can't be sure.

Comment: Dear Ian, thank you. I inherited the code from a researcher who wrote it years ago. it solves 3D TDSE :) . I am not familiar with Fortran, I am just learning it to be able to intelligently go through this code and (I hope) make it better as the results are not converged for the maximum parameters for which the code runs in < 4 days of wall-clock time (i.e. a reasonable upper bound for a simulation). The code did not include any form of parallelization with OpenMP and my thoughts have been that I could improve it by the above modification.

Comment: 1. make your loop variables `l,j` private 2. Since each `l,j` pair writes to disjoint locations the parallel version will compute the same as sequential 3. You are writing to contiguous locations `(:,l,j)` so data access will be fairly efficient.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, thank you very much. Please, what do you mean that the ``parallel version will compute the same as sequential`` ? Do you refer to the fact that if I made the loop variable ``l`` private (see that I only parallelize the outer-most do-loop, also there's no ``j`` variable in here) then the parallel version will end up ``with the same results`` as the serial one?

Comment: An obvious mistake is that `m` should be private. Apart from that the parallelization looks ok, including for the performances. However, the memory access pattern is not very good, including for the sequential code. We'd like to switch the `j` and `m` loops, but I'm not sure it's possible. The other solution would would to rearrange the `U` and `U2` arrays, by switching the second and third dimensions.